# Bold Text Back to Regular in C#

Tags: c#, text, textbox

I have changed my text to bold by this code
 "textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);"
 now can anyone guide me how do I change my text to normal by pressing the same button

Comment: You can add a click tracker and increment the number each time. As an example, if the int tracker is odd then make it bold if it is even then make it non bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = "aaa";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, (textBox1.Font.Style == FontStyle.Bold) ? FontStyle.Regular : FontStyle.Bold);
       }
}
```

for more reference:

[?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

[Font Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why not this? `textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, (counter % 2 == 0) ? FontStyle.Regular : FontStyle.Bold);`

Furthermore, I think a `bool` variable would make much more sense.

Comment: Why introduce a counter or additional variable when you can just check the existing font's `FontStyle` property and flip it? This is inefficient and dangerous because you have not handled the (unlikely) case where you reach `Int32.Max`, either.

Comment: @Andrew  you are both right. thanks for advice and editted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [`FontStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) reference page in MSDN, it clearly states that you can use `FontStyle.Regular` to output normal (non-bold) text.